# Retrieving a Single ROW from Database

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `listview`, when a user clicks on an item from the `listview`, it calls a function `getRow`, which takes the id of the clicked item and retrieves the Name of the clicked item.

However, when I click the item, i am able to retrieve the ID, but it doesn't want to run the query to retrieve the rest of the information.

Here is my code, and logcat:

#### UserDbHelper.java (class)

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    UserDbHelper userDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USERINFO.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY =

            "CREATE TABLE "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ROWID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+
                    UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_MOBILE+" TEXT,"+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT);";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ROWID, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_MOBILE, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};

    public UserDbHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "DATABASE CREATED/ OPENED...");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "TABLE CREATED...");


    }

    public void addInformations(String name, String mob, String email, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_MOBILE,mob);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL,email);

        sqLiteDatabase.insert(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "ONE ROW INSERTED....");
    }

    public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        Cursor cursor;

        String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_MOBILE, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections,null,null,null,null,null);

        return cursor;
    }

    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ROWID +"="+ rowId;
        Log.e("ID= ",where);

        String select = "SELECT "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME+" FROM "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+where;
        Log.e("query = ", select);
        db.execSQL(select);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

#### ListView.java (Activity that handles the click events)

```
    public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ListView listView;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;;
        UserDbHelper user;
        Cursor cursor;
        ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

            listView = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
            listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

            user = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
            sqLiteDatabase = user.getReadableDatabase();

            cursor = user.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String name, mob, email;
                    name = cursor.getString(0);
                    mob = cursor.getString(1);
                    email = cursor.getString(2);

                    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name,mob,email);

                    listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long ldatabase) {
                    Cursor cursor = user.getRow(i);
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        long idDb = cursor.getLong(0);
                        String message = "ID is: " +idDb;
                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

The `OnItemClickListener`, gets the id of the clicked item, passes that value to the `UserDbHelper` class, to the function `getRow`, where the function takes the id, and runs a query, however when it wants to run the query it, it crashes my app.

I also printed the ID in the logcat to check if i was getting an id, which i was.

#### Here is the LOGCAT:

```
01-12 17:40:47.574 13309-13309/bluwyreinc.rohansfitness E/ID=: _id=6
01-12 17:40:47.574 13309-13309/bluwyreinc.rohansfitness E/query =: SELECT user_name FROM user_info WHERE _id=6
01-12 17:40:47.575 13309-13309/bluwyreinc.rohansfitness E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: bluwyreinc.rohansfitness, PID: 13309
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at bluwyreinc.rohansfitness.UserDbHelper.getRow(UserDbHelper.java:68)
                                                                              at bluwyreinc.rohansfitness.ListActivity$1.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:54)
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:343)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1665)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4075)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView$10.run(AbsListView.java:6552)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
01-12 17:40:48.090 3104-3160/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedbluwyreinc.rohansfitness/bluwyreinc.rohansfitness.MainActivity/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your this method:

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ROWID +"="+ rowId;
        Log.e("ID= ",where);

        String select = "SELECT "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME+" FROM "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+where;
        Log.e("query = ", select);

        // Here db is null.
        db.execSQL(select);

        return null;
    }
```

Pass it `sqLiteDatabase` and It should be returning the cursor, something like this:

```
public Cursor getRow(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, long rowId) {
        String where = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ROWID +"="+ rowId;
        Log.e("ID= ",where);

        String select = "SELECT "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME+" FROM "+ UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+where;
        Log.e("query = ", select);
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(select);

        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! it helped, i had to tweak my ListActivity.java a little bit, but it worked. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

You never set any value to `db` field, so when you try to use it, it's null and causes your crash. You should ensure db is not null before using it

Comment: so something like `if(db == null){ db.open() }` or if you don't mind dumbing it down for me, cause my brain is just not understanding whats going on with that

Comment: With that you will still have a crash because you can't do `db.open()` if `db` is not instantiated. You need to set `db = whateverDb` at some point, or to provide the database as a parameter of your `getRow` method